# Getting Linked issues and Projects associated with a pull request form github api v3

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request, github-api-v3

How can I get the Projects and linked issues for a given pull request from github API V3? The `pulls` endpoint does not give information on either of them. 
In the github's pull requests section's sidebar there are `Projects` and `Linked issues` mentioned. But I could not find a way to get this information via API calls.

[Screenshot of the sidebar for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGURX.png)

I want to find out which issues a pull request closes on merging successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the projects with cards linking to a specific pull request you can use [Github GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) using this payload :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "twbs", name: "bootstrap") {
    pullRequest(number: 30342) {
      projectCards {
        nodes {
          project {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But for the linked issues I don't think the API is available yet. You can still **scrape** the list from github.com if the repo is public. The following [python](/questions/tagged/python) script get the list of issues URL using [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) :

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

repo = "twbs/bootstrap"
pr = "30342"

r = requests.get(f"https://github.com/{repo}/pull/{pr}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
issueForm = soup.find("form", { "aria-label": re.compile('Link issues')})

print([ i["href"] for i in issueForm.find_all("a")])
```

Answer (score 6):

2022 Update:

There is now a closingIssuesReferences property on pull requests in GraphQL.

```
pullRequest(number: $number) {
    id
    closingIssuesReferences (first: 50) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          body
          number
          title
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*(Post this here in case it's helpful for anyone else looking to get Issues linked to a Pull Request)*

There's no direct way of getting a list of Issues linked to a Pull Request.

But each Pull Request includes a timeline of events and one of those events is when an Issue gets linked. Using the timeline of events I was able to write a GitHub APIv4 API request and some javascript to get the Issues linked to a PR:

First, here's the GraphQL query:

```
{
  resource(url: "https://github.com/Org/Project/pull/1234") {
    ... on PullRequest {
      timelineItems(itemTypes: [CONNECTED_EVENT, DISCONNECTED_EVENT], first: 100) {
        nodes {
          ... on ConnectedEvent {
            id
            subject {
              ... on Issue {
                number
              }
            }
          }
          ... on DisconnectedEvent {
            id
            subject {
              ... on Issue {
                number
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you run this in the GitHub GraphQL Explorer (https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/), you'll see all the events that an Issue was connected and disconnected to a Pull Request.

Using that query, I pass the response to this code that I wrote for a nodejs app that then determines which Issue is still linked to the Pull Request

```
const issues = {};
resource.timelineItems.nodes.map(node => {
    if (issues.hasOwnProperty(node.subject.number)) {
        issues[node.subject.number]++;
    } else {
        issues[node.subject.number] = 1;
    }
});
const linkedIssues = [];
for (const [issue, count] of Object.entries(issues)) {
    if (count % 2 != 0) {
        linkedIssues.push(issue);
    }
}
console.log(issues);

console.log(linkedIssues);
```

The logic here is as follows:

1. Get a list of all events on a Pull Request of the type CONNECTED_EVENT and DISCONNECTED_EVENT
2. Create a map, keyed by Issue number and keep a count of how may times the issue is CONNECTED and DISCONNECTED
3. From that map, look for keys that have an odd-numbered count, as these are the events that have been CONNECTED that don't have a corresponding DISCONNECTED event.

It's not a super elegant solution, but it solves what I need, which was to find those Linked issues.

Hopefully this helps someone else out

Comment: I've tried your solution replacing the pull request url with https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/30342 which has 4 linked issues but it returned nothing, maybe I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the following query should return the linked pull request numbers for an issue. However it returns an error message hinting about internal error right now. I opened a ticket at github about it.

(project kode-konveyor/TaskMarket, issue #121)

```
{
  repository(owner: "kode-konveyor", name: "TaskMarket") {
    issue(number: 121) {
      id
      number
      title
      timelineItems {
        __typename
        ... on IssueTimelineItemsConnection {
          nodes {
            __typename
            ... on ConnectedEvent {
              source {
                __typename
                ... on PullRequest {
                  number
                }
              }
              subject {
                __typename
                ... on PullRequest {
                  number
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find linked PRs from Issues and vice-versa. Not exactly what you're asking, but this was the most relevant SO post I could find.

Fully working Python implementation (PyGithub):

```py
def get_linked_pr_from_issue(issue: Issue) -> PullRequest | None:
  """Check if the given issue has a linked pull request.

  This function iterates over the timeline of the issue and checks if there is a 'cross-referenced' event.
  If such an event is found, it checks if the source of the event is an issue and if so, it returns the issue as a pull request.

  Usage: 
  issue: Issue = repo.get_issue(number=8)
  pr_or_none = check_if_issue_has_linked_pr(issue)

  Args:
      issue (Issue): The issue to check for a linked pull request.

  Returns:
      PullRequest: The linked pull request if it exists, None otherwise.
  """
  events_pages: PaginatedList[TimelineEvent] = issue.get_timeline()
  pg_num = 0
  while events_pages.get_page(pg_num):
    page = events_pages.get_page(pg_num)
    pg_num += 1
    for e in page:
      if str(e.event) == 'cross-referenced':
        if e.source and e.source.issue:
            return e.source.issue.as_pull_request()

def get_linked_issue_from_pr(pr: PullRequest) -> Issue | None:
  """Check if the given pull request has a linked issue.

  This function iterates over the timeline of the pull request and checks if there is a 'cross-referenced' event.
  If such an event is found, it checks if the source of the event is a pull request and if so, it returns the pull request as an issue.

  Usage: 
  pr: PullRequest = repo.get_pull(number=8)
  issue_or_none = check_if_pr_has_linked_issue(pr)

  Args:
      pr (PullRequest): The pull request to check for a linked issue.

  Returns:
      Issue: The linked issue if it exists, None otherwise.
  """
  events_pages: PaginatedList[TimelineEvent] = pr.as_issue().get_timeline()
  pg_num = 0
  while events_pages.get_page(pg_num):
    page = events_pages.get_page(pg_num)
    pg_num += 1
    for e in page:
      if str(e.event) == 'cross-referenced':
        if e.source and e.source.issue:
            return e.source.issue
```